# Host USB device connections disabled

Tags: windows-7, usb, services

I have a problem regarding VMware.

> Host USB device connections disabled
>
> The connection to the VMware USB Arbitration Service was
>   unsuccessful. Please check the status of this service in the Microsoft
>   Management Console.

I am working on Windows 7 64-bit as Host and BT4 as Guest.I am using VMware Workstation 7.1.3 build-324285.

The problem message appears at the beginning of the VM starting up.

I have checked all the steps in these tutorials:

- http://ericwijaya.wordpress.com/2010/03/12/vmware-usb-cannot-connect-to-host-usb/
- http://mooremn.wordpress.com/2010/06/27/vmware-player-error-host-usb-device-connections-disabled/

Here's some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]